# OpenERP Export to Excel error

Tags: byte, ascii, odoo, decode

I'm currently trying to export the info from a menu to excel, the problem is on relations.

[image]

I have several fields which have relations (many2one, etc), those menus don't have any kind of accents in their field_names. I only put accents in the string/description. Example:

```
"centro_custo":fields.many2one('classA.classA', 'Descrição', select = True)
```

So, whenever I try to click the arrow to expand, it gives me this error:

[image]

I currently have, in the top of each file .py: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
I need to expand the arrow because of the relations..if I do not expand, whenever I export the data it comes in this format: 
**export**.classA_costs_1_1

**export**.classA_costs_2_2

Any advice?

Comment: Well, I found that the problem was on the 'description' field..
This is not possible:
`"centro_custo":fields.char("Descrição", size = 30)`

It retrieves that error..so, instead of that it should be:
`"centro_custo":fields.char("description", size = 30)`
And then, in the xml code:
`<field name="centro_custo" string="Descrição"/>`

Although, the columns exported to Excel get the string "description" instead of "Descrição"..so I didn't solved this yet. 
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, solve it.
Whenever your string contains accents, you should write "u" before the string.
`"centro_custo":fields.char(u"Descrição", size = 30)`

Comment: Aff..I'm still getting troubles with this..if anyone knows a better solution..I have the file save in notepad++ in UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: It was my fault, seems that this kind of character "ç" also needs the 'u' behind.

Comment: The error was regarding trying to represent a unicode character in ascii. The u'abc' is a short hand for the unicode function and unicode does handle non-ascii characters of course.